# Bug rendering spoilers with tags in them

Tags: bug, markdown

As can be seen in [this answer to the secret hats thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270993/223467), it seems that spoiler and tag markdowns don't play well together - the tag markdown within a spoiler markdown is clearly visible:

[image]